# How to cache all javascript and stylesheets in one file in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

```
$rails -v
Rails 3.1.1
```

I tried this:

```
javascript_include_tag 'application', cache: true
```

But error occurs:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Then how can I cache all javascripts(& stylesheets) to one cache file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Rails 3.1 caching is automatically handled by the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have just found that, and successfully got my app to run. The asset pipeline is really awesome!  :D